# LDAP configuration parameter, what does "?one" mean?

Tags: linux, ldap

I am configuring the Debian package nsslib-ldap and am wondering about one of the configuration options. The config file I'm editing is called 'libnss-ldap.conf'. The line in question is:

nss_base_group ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com?one

I understand everything except the "?one". What does that do? I can tell that the rest of the command means "look for group information from this distinguished name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a parameter describing the LDAP search scope and means that all relevant entries are one level below the base given.

It would find `cn=groupname,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com`, but not `cn=subgroup,ou=groupname,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com`.

Comment: Thanks SvenW, this mostly answers my question. After some more searching, I found on Wikipedia that the format for this is "ldap://host:port/DN?attributes?scope?filter?extensions". Why then is there "?one" instead of "??one" at the end. The "?one" is a scope parameter, is it not? Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol#LDAP_URLs

Comment: The exact query string is build from different parts in the config file. You'll notice it's missing the `ldap://host:port` part as well. This is set elsewhere.

Comment: Great. This explains everything. Thanks for your help!